# last position null ListView Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

In my class of adapter I'm having problems getView method (). When I print the positions of the elements that I want to list, always missing the last but repeated the first. For example, I have an array of my class of RowItem (custom) class with 7 elements. The positions I get is:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("Position : "+position);
    return null
}

Position : 0
Position : 1
Position : 2
Position : 3
Position : 4
Position : 5
.....
```

However, if the method getCount print receipt

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("Count "+getCount());
    return null;
}

Count : 7
Count : 7
Count : 7
Count : 7
Count : 7
Count : 7
```

This causes, that my last element is always like the first. On my list I have a button that when you click, modify a value in the cell to which the button belongs. But this error, it modified only visually the first element and the last. My class :

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;
private ArrayList<RowItem> items;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
    List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    this.items.addAll(items);
}

/*private view holder class*/
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtNombre;
    TextView txtTicket;
    TextView txtAsiento;
    TextView txtOrden;
    TextView txtNumero;
    TextView txtMensaje;
    TextView txtAdicionales;
    TextView txtOtros;
    TextView txtCategoria;
    Button btn; 
 }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public RowItem getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

As I call this class from my activity

```
CustomListViewAdapter adapter;
public List<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
rowItems = nueva.getInscripcionsByRut(ValidacionMultiple.this, rut_inscripcion);
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(ValidacionMultiple.this,R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple, rowItems );
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Method getInscripcionsByRut

```
public List<RowItem> getInscripcionsByRut(Context context, String rut){
    inscripcionValida = new Inscripcions();
    List<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    RowItem item;
    bdTickets = new TicketsBaseDatos(context, Config.NAME_DATABASE, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = bdTickets.getWritableDatabase();
    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
    String codigoEvento = manager.getValue(context, "codigoEvento");
    String[] args = new String[] {rut,codigoEvento};
    String codigo_checkin = manager.getValue(context, "checkin");
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Inscripcion WHERE rut=? AND codigo_evento=?",args);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
         item = new RowItem();
         inscripcionValida.setId(c.getInt(0));
         inscripcionValida.setHash(c.getString(1));
         inscripcionValida.setCodigo_evento(c.getString(2));
         inscripcionValida.setTicket(c.getString(3));
         inscripcionValida.setNombre(c.getString(4));
         inscripcionValida.setInscripcion_id(c.getString(5));
         inscripcionValida.setValidado(c.getInt(6));
         inscripcionValida.setSincronizado(c.getInt(7));
         inscripcionValida.setNumero(c.getString(8));
         inscripcionValida.setAsiento(c.getString(9));
         inscripcionValida.setAdicionales(c.getString(10));
         inscripcionValida.setOtros(c.getString(11));
         inscripcionValida.setCategoria(c.getString(12));
         inscripcionValida.setRut(c.getString(14));
         inscripcionValida.setTalla(c.getString(15));
         inscripcionValida.setNombreResponsable(c.getString(17));
         inscripcionValida.setFechaValidacion(c.getString(16));
         item.setAsiento(inscripcionValida.getAsiento());
         item.setNumero(inscripcionValida.getNumero());
         item.setHash(inscripcionValida.getHash());
         item.setNombre(inscripcionValida.getNombre());
         item.setTicket(inscripcionValida.getTicket());
         item.setOtros(inscripcionValida.getOtros());
         item.setAdicionales(inscripcionValida.getAdicionales());
         if(manager.getValue(context,"checkin") != null){
             item.setValidado(checkinValidado(context,inscripcionValida.getInscripcion_id(),codigo_checkin));
         }else{
             item.setValidado(inscripcionValida.getValidado());
         }
         item.setId_inscripcion(Integer.parseInt(inscripcionValida.getInscripcion_id()));
         rowItems.add(item); 
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return rowItems;
}
```

It is also sending data from my DB to my List to display in the listview.

I got my method getView like this:

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println(getCount());
    ViewHolder holder;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtNombre = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        holder.btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.txtMensaje = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtNombre.setText(Html.fromHtml("Nombre: <b>"+rowItem.getNombre()+"</b>"));
    if(rowItem.getValidado()==1){
        holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_alert);
        holder.btn.setText("");
        holder.txtMensaje.setText("E-ticket ya validado");
    }else{
        holder.btn.setTag(position);
        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           //More code...
        });
    }
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```

What happens here is that if I click on the button of the first item or the last item, you get the same data and do not correspond.

Comment: how many total items are visible at any time in the list? 6 or 7?

Comment: I get 7 elements. Each cell has a TextView my list and also a button. Clicking on the button, I do a procedure in my database. The problem I am having is that the last element, the button works with the position of the first, as to get 5, the position becomes 0 and therefore my button gets the tag position. I'll add more code to be well understood. @ankitaggarwal

Comment: what i am asking is after your list is inflated, how many total items out of 7 you are able to see at a time without scrolling the list. are all the 7 items visible all the times, or is it less that 7. Just put your getView() method. Currently you are returning null in getview()

Comment: Add the actual method code getView, please look and tell me if you find any errors

Answer (score 1):

Just add `holder.btn.setOnClickListener(null);` in the if condition.

```
if(rowItem.getValidado()==1){  
     holder.btn.setOnClickListener(null);
}else{
     holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
          RowItem item_click = getItem(position);
          Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
          b.setTag(position);
          //More elements.
     });
}
```

The inconsistent behaviour you see is because of view recycling in listview. Your views for list items are recycled and reused. Say you list has got 100 items so 100 different views will not be created. It will only create unique views approximately equal to the number of items visible in the list. So if a item disappears from the list, its view is not destroyed, it is given to the other items.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
```

here convertView is the view that gets recycled

Now in your code you assigned a onClickListener to one view. For the 7th item, the earlier would have been recycled for which onClickListener has already been set. So just remove that onClickListener on whichever row you don't want the listener to be present

Comment: I believe everything you say is correct, but unfortunately this still fails for me. I click on the first button and change both the first and the last.

Comment: but after adding holder.btn.setOnClickListener(null); you should not be able to click on 1st item right?

Comment: I've always been able to click on the first or the last button, what happens is that the button appears to be the same, apparently holder.btn.setTag (position); The position value returns to 0 and therefore what you do with the button of the first or last item is always the same.

Comment: Its weird. although the buttons are same but for different positions, listeners are different. Infact for the first position we are setting the listener as null. Anyways i'll check if anything else is wrong in your code.

Comment: It was printing the position and the item corresponding when you click on the button and it works well, send the data well but I think the problem lies in the following, please note in my code getView () in the event onClick when visual elements, button, Textview, etc. are initialized I think that's the error, since the value of the item and position are correct. I need to get the holder.btn from the onClick event but I can not, asks me ViewHolder holder is final. perhaps because there is the error?

Comment: And it is!! that was the mistake, add in onClick event b.setTag (position); and deliver all elements setTag (position), Please, edit your answer and add that to give as correct answer !, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: My happiness was short-lived, still fails jajajaja

Comment: why are you even using tag for position while you can achieve things without using that also.

Comment: I realized now that probe with a list of 100 data, which is the scroll the listview something does fail, I clicked one button, when applying scroll on my list changed around 2 items, then did the same, and now were 2 but 5, and so on, until all changed ... that mistake more annoying you? : S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104445/discussion-between-sioesi-and-ankit-aggarwal).